# Why is s[0] is an empty string for an empty string s in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

The C++ Primer tell me that `s[s.size()]` should be unpredictable.

But I tried many times, and insert it into other codes, `s[0]` is always an empty string. But when `s` is not an empty string, trying to access `s[size()]` will throw an error.

Why is the empty string special?

Comment: What exactly s is?

Comment: Please try to express your question more clearly. *"s[0] is always an empty string"* doesn't even make sense, because `s[0]` is a `char`, so it can never be a string of any kind, empty or not.

Comment: I am sorry that my expression is not clear, because English is not my mother tongue, and English learning is not universal in my country.Sorry again;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Member access on a string produces a *character*, not a string.

C++11 guarantees that `s[s.size()]` is 0. C++17 even allows you to *write* to `s[s.size()]`, provided that you are writing the value 0:

> [regarding `operator[](size_type pos)`:]
>
> *Requires*: `pos <= size()`.
>
> *Returns*: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type
> `charT` with value `charT()`, where modifying the object to any value other than `charT()` leads to undefined behavior.

(`charT()` is standardese for "zero".)

Prior to C++17 the last sentence didn't contain the words "to any value other than `charT()`". This was overly restrictive, e.g. forbidding `strcpy`ing into a string of the correct size.